# cmake command issue while compile project of tbb

Tags: makefile, cmake, tbb

I tried using a demo to compile tbb in my project.
Link of the demo https://www.selectiveintellect.net/blog/2016/7/29/using-cmake-to-add-third-party-libraries-to-your-project-1

IDE for me is VS2013 and get an error about command 'make'

```
Performing build step for 'tbb44'
2>  CMake Error at F:/CPPs/FAsT-Match-master/build/tbb44/src/tbb44-stamp/tbb44-build-Debug.cmake:49 (message):
2>    Command failed: 2
2>  
2>     'make' 'tbb_build_prefix=tbb44'
```

The original command is generated via tbb.cmake, for which it looks like

```
ExternalProject_Add(${TBB_PREFIX}
    PREFIX ${TBB_PREFIX}
    URL ${TBB_URL}
    URL_MD5 ${TBB_URL_MD5}
    CONFIGURE_COMMAND ""
#   BUILD_COMMAND ${TBB_MAKE} -j${NCPU} tbb_build_prefix=${TBB_PREFIX}
    BUILD_COMMAND ${TBB_MAKE} tbb_build_prefix=${TBB_PREFIX}
```

The one commented is the original and the one behind is modified.
Is this the problem of MSVC?

Comment: You really have Visual Studio 2013 on extended support? I'm so sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That blog post is just *completely* wrong. TBB comes with its own CMake build now, so there's absolutely no reason to go through ExternalProject like this.

Here's how I built it from source, using Visual Studio 2019 (the instructions should be pretty much the same). From a developer command prompt, using CMake 3.20:

```
D:\>git clone https://github.com/oneapi-src/oneTBB
D:\>cmake -S oneTBB -B oneTBB-build -DTBB_TEST=OFF
D:\>cmake --build oneTBB-build --config Release
D:\>cmake --build oneTBB-build --config Debug
D:\>cmake --install oneTBB-build --prefix oneTBB-install --config Release
D:\>cmake --install oneTBB-build --prefix oneTBB-install --config Debug
```

Setting `TBB_TEST` to `OFF` saves a lot of time waiting on TBB's tests to build. These commands install the Debug and Release binaries to `D:\oneTBB-install`. Of course, you can place this folder anywhere you like.

Once this is done, you may use your new TBB build from your project like so:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20)
project(TBB-test)

find_package(TBB REQUIRED)

add_executable(main main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(main PRIVATE TBB::tbb)
```

The `TBB` package also includes libraries `TBB::tbbmalloc` and `TBB::tbbmalloc_proxy`.

When you build your project, you may point `find_package` to your TBB installation by setting the CMake variable `TBB_ROOT` to `D:/oneTBB-install` at the command line via:

```
D:\>cmake -S myProject -B myProject-build -DTBB_ROOT=D:/oneTBB-install
```